# Junit Testing methods and constructors in separate classes

Tags: java, junit

I am looking for good practice about testing constructor and methods in Junit. In my currently project, I testing constructor and method in separate test class. For example, I have Monitor class. MonitorTestConstructors class test a constructor for various parameters and validate created object but also check exception witch constructor throw. In MonitorTestMethod class, I test methods but object is created in @Before method. Is it good practice? How do you deal with it? What are your opinions/experiences about that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A couple tips:

Class naming convention generally is such that test class names are a concatenation of "Test" and the class it is testing, in your case class TestMonitor.

There is no rule that you need to use the @Before annotation anywhere.  That's typically used for initializing dependencies like file paths and other objects that you aren't testing.

Keep the FIRST (FAST, ISOLATED, REPEATABLE, SELF-VALIDATING, THOROUGH) principles in mind, where "ISOLATED" is most pertinent to your question.  You should instantiate a new Monitor() object in each test method, rather than recycling the same instance for each test, because in the case of failures in a complex testing sequence it will be harder than necessary to de-bug.